# self.ids not changing text of button | kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from numpy import linspace as linspace
from numpy import arange as arange
import sympy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

def formatted(f):
    return float(format(f, '.2f').rstrip('0').rstrip('.'))

class GraphWindow(Screen):
    def graph(self):
        global m
        global b
        global bs
        m = int(self.ids.mvalue.text)
        b = int(self.ids.bvalue.text)

        if i == 1:
            plot(m, b)


class ResultWindow(Screen):
    def displayresult(self):
        out = f"out: \n y = {m}x{bs}"
        print(out)
        self.ids.out.text = out


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("graph.kv")


class graphApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


graphApp().run()
```

Python script^

```
<ResultWindow>:
    name: "result"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Button:
            id: out
            text: 'error'
```

kv file^

Ive looked online and couldnt find a solution, the problem is that in "resultwindow" i try to change the text of a button and it just wont update anything about the button.

I had to remove most of the python script because it wouldn't let me post.
https://pastebin.com/Ap6Vdu90

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are changing the `text` in another instance of `ResultWindow` not in the one you added to your `root`.

So in order to get expected outcome you have to access that `ResultWindow` from your `root` widget, which you can get by the static method `get_running_app` of the class `App`.

Thus the change you might need is,

```py
class ResultWindow(Screen):
    def displayresult(self):
        out = f"out: \n y = {m}x{bs}"
        print(out)
        app = App.get_running_app() # Accessing instance of currently running app.
        out_btn = app.root.get_screen("result").ids.out # Accessing the root, required screen and ids of that screen.
        out_btn.text = out
```

Comment: Thanks very much, great answer.